I blocked/I've blocked him
A: "I saw John today. He said he keeps calling you, but you're not answering his calls."
B: "I blocked/I've blocked him."
A: "Why?"
B: "He kept texting me a lot of weird stuff. I told him to stop, but he wouldn't listen."
In the dialog above, we have a present state (John is now blocked) resulting from a past action. According to its definition, the present perfect "I've blocked" should be used here.
Do American English speakers say "I blocked", while British English speakers say "I've blocked" in this case? Thanks.

Yes. Americans tend to avoid perfect tenses.

Plenty of American speakers would use the present perfect.

Here's my verdict: I am so tired of the myth re the varieties of English and the present perfect. Have I made myself clear? :)

Both are fine. There's not enough difference in meaning to worry about. There may be some variation between dialects but it is a tendency not a rule.
It is like you can say "He's unhappy" or "He's sad" and there's no real difference in meaning (even though in other contexts there would be a difference).  You can use either past tense or present perfect, and there is not real difference in meaning (even though in other contexts there would be a difference)
